# How to launch LMT pie controls with home button

Tags: home-button

I have an acer iconia tab a100 running a custom ROM based on CM10.1. The tab has one hardware button, the home button. I'd prefer to use LMT pie controls rather than the navigation bar to save screen space, but I don't like having to launch pie controls with gestures.

My question is: is there some way for me to remap the home button on the tab to launch pie controls instead of the default action, going to the home screen?